# org.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to com.parse.ParseGeoPoint

Tags: android, json, parse-platform

```
private class MyObject {
        private String itemName;
        private int itemPrice;
        private ParseGeoPoint location;
        private MyObject(JSONObject obj) {
            try {
                itemName = obj.getString("Item").toLowerCase().trim();
                itemPrice = obj.getInt("Price");
                location = (ParseGeoPoint) obj.get("Location");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Utility.showMessage(e.getMessage(), "Oops!", SalesReportActivity.this);
            }
        }
        public String toString() {
            return "Name: " + itemName + "\n" +
                   "Price: " + itemPrice;
        }
    }
```

For the above code Android is giving me the exception above. I've also tried getJSONObject() but the result is the same. What should I do?

Comment: change this `location = (ParseGeoPoint) obj.get("Location");`to `location = (JSONObject) obj.get("Location");`. Declare location as a jsonobject

Comment: Solution is in your question header....

Comment: Thanks Raghunandan, your solution worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj.get("Location")` returning JSONObject,so first get `Location` JSONObject from `obj` and both `latitude` and `longitude` values :

```
            JSONObject jsonLocation = obj.getJSONObject("Location");
            double latitude=jsonLocation.getDouble("latitude");
            double longitude=jsonLocation.getDouble("longitude");   
            location=new ParseGeoPoint(latitude, longitude)
```